# How to access and show the preference attribute of Marketing Cloud of a customer in another website?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a website in a development stage, there is a link provided in it where users can click it and see information about their preference in Marketing Cloud. Is it possible by using a hyper link or an API trigger in my website or by any means to access their information about their preference saved in Marketing Cloud, and show it in my website in a popup or redirecting it to a new page? My website in not integrated with Marketing Cloud.

Comment: do you mean inside of a data extension or all subscribers preferences?

Comment: You use the REST APi calls if your preference data is inside the data extension.

Comment: In all subscribers preferences.